# Как указать переменную в PHP и JS

Tags: javascript, php

Есть на сайте кнопка `Оплатить`, рядом с ней, в зависимости от выбранного товара, рядом меняется и цена.

[image: Выбран товар, отображается сумма]

В коде это выглядит так:

```
<p class="label">Итог:&nbsp;</p>
<p class="total">{{currentProduct.fprice}}</p>
```

После этих строк, ниже, есть `<script>`, в котором выполняется функция при клике на "Оплатить".

Эта функция выполняет переадресацию при клике на платежную систему QIWI, т.к. работаю с QIWI API.
В той самой функции есть строка с кодом:

```
var urlQiwi = 'https://oplata.qiwi.com/create?publicKey=' + qiwiToken + '&amount=' + sum + '&successUrl=***';
```

Мне нужно чтобы `{{currentProduct.fprice}}` (35 RUB, и т.д., т.е. та цена, на какую нажмет пользователь) подставлялась в запрос, на место `+ sum +`.

Не могу обойтись сам, т.к. не знаю каким образом сформулировать гуглу свою проблему.

Посмотрел JS справочник, ничего толкового не нашел. Подставлял `{{currentProduct.fprice}}` вместо `+ sum +`, выдавало ошибку (оно и понятно).

Хотелось бы узнать, как достать выбранную сумму и записать ее в URL запрос?

Comment: А php тут причом? или этот код в php?
<p class="total">{{currentProduct.fprice}}</p> Ну и по этим кусам кода встряли кто то тебе сможет написать все четко, Много не понятно короче, из за отсутствия остальных данных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `sum` вставить: `document.querySelector('.total').innerText`

Comment: Благодарю! Столкнулся сразу с еще одним недочётом, есть Итог: 3,790 RUB, при нажатии на Оплатить вылезает "Оплата 3 RUB (в самом киви уже)", видимо читает только целые числа, точку нельзя никак убрать?

Comment: @DrinkWithMe, Конечно можно, но строго не рекомендуется брать данные, которые берутся просто со страницы. Потому, что сюда `document.querySelector('.total').innerText` можно через код элемента подставить всё что угодно.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, ты используешь vue.js. Тогда вместо `sum` поставь `this.currentProduct.fprice`.

Однако вычисления, касающиеся методов оплаты, крайне рекомендуется проводить *исключительно на стороне **сервера***. В целях безопасности.